# Finding all documents which share the same value in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider I have the following data below:

```
{
  "id":123,
  "name":"apple",
  "codes":["ABC", "DEF", "EFG"]
}
{
  "id":234,
  "name":"pineapple",
  "codes":["DEF"]
}
{
  "id":345,
  "name":"banana",
  "codes":["HIJ","KLM"]
}
```

If I didn't want to search by a specific code, is there a way to find all fruits in my mongodb collection which shares the same code?

Comment: probably ids are different and codes in the first document is an array, right?

Comment: Yes! I've made an edit. The ids should all be unique. Codes is also an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$codes' },
    { $group: { _id: '$codes', count: {$sum:1}, fruits: {$push: '$name'}}},
    { $match: {'count': {$gt:1}}},   
    { $group:{_id:null, total:{$sum:1}, data:{$push:{fruits: '$fruits', code:'$_id'}}}}


])
```

result:

```
{ "_id" : null, "total" : 1, "data" : [ { "fruits" : [ "apple", "pineapple" ], "code" : "DEF" } ] }
```

Comment: Is there a way I can count how many results total produces an aggregate with count gt 1?